Efficient Data Sync to Google Drive with Rate Limits
We manage an application for a client who has over 9 PB of Google Drive space. The app sends data to an 8 TB HDD on a Linux server, which needs to be accessible via a web UI with good load speeds. Currently, there’s no fail-safe for this HDD, and the client is unwilling to invest in additional hardware or alternative backup services.
We attempted to sync data to Google Drive using Google’s API via rclone and numerous other tools but are facing severe speed limits. Despite a 1 Gbps public uplink, our upload speeds are capped at 5 Mbps to Google, making the transfer of nearly 3 TB of data extremely slow (700 GB could take a month).
Options explored:

rclone sync and other sync tools: Slow upload speeds.
Mount Google Drive on Linux via rclone: Slow web UI access due to network performance.

Alternative approach:
Local: Set up a local network link between the Linux server and a Windows server, map the 8 TB drive to the Windows server, and use the Google Drive app on Windows, which reportedly has no rate limits.
Questions:

How can we bypass or mitigate Google Drive’s upload speed limits for faster uploads from a Linux server using our sync tools?

Is using the Google Drive app on Windows a viable solution, or will we still face similar limits?


Any advice on optimising this process would be greatly appreciated, we really want to use the 9 PB drive.

https://cloud.google.com/transfer-appliance/docs/4.0/overview

Yeah, that's not going to work when there are no Google DCs close to me.
